# How to get select option name attribute in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to get a select option name attribute in vuejs. I tried it to value attributes. It worked well. I have mentioned the tried code below.

Tried code:

```
<select id="countryselect" name="country" @change="onChange()">
  <option value="1" name="0">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="2" name="0">Albania</option>
  <option value="3" name="0">Algeria</option>
  <option value="4" name="1">Malaysia</option>
  <option value="5" name="0">Maldives</option>
</select>

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    onChange: function() {
      //this workes well
      var b = event.target.value;
      // this not workes
      var c = event.target.name;
    }
  },
});
```

I want to know how can I do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.target.name` actually returns the `name` attribute of the `select` element instead of the selected `option`. To get the `name` attribute of the selected `option` you can use [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method instead like:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    onChange: function() {
      var options = event.target.options
      if (options.selectedIndex > -1) {
        var name = options[options.selectedIndex].getAttribute('name');
        console.log(name)
      }
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select id="countryselect" name="country" @change="onChange()">
    <option value="0">---Select---</option>
    <option value="1" name="0">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="2" name="0">Albania</option>
    <option value="3" name="0">Algeria</option>
    <option value="4" name="1">Malaysia</option>
    <option value="5" name="0">Maldives</option>
  </select>
</div>
```