# Vue.js select dropdown option selected attribute problem

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following code for a select dropdown in html:

```
<select class="form-select" name="" id="" v-model="rp">
<option v-for="(educationGroup,index) in educationGroupList" :key="index" :value='educationGroup.id' :v-if="educationGroup.id == 2" selected>{{ educationGroup.name }}</option>
</select>
```

My problem is how can i set selected attribute in vue.js. IN my code "selected" code doesn't work.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62463727/how-to-get-select-option-name-attribute-in-vuejs

Answer (score 1):

You can try calling an change event with @change

```js
  <select class="form-select" name="" id="" v-model="rp" @change="onChange()">
    <option v-for="(educationGroup,index) in educationGroupList" :key="index" :value='educationGroup.id' :v-if="educationGroup.id == 2" selected>{{ educationGroup.name }}</option>
</select>
```

And then call onChange function in methods to get selected value as below:

```js
export default {

    methods: {
    onChange: function() {
      var options = event.target.options
      if (options.selectedIndex > -1) {
        var value= options[options.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value');
        console.log(value)
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the selection with two options.

Option 1: Use **v-model**.

In this scenario, the value assigned for `v-model` should match with the `value` for option.

Example: In my example the `value` for `option` is assigned as `educationGroup.id` where `educationGroup` is individual objects in array `educationGroupList`

```
<select class="form-select" name="" id="" v-model="rp">
  <option
    v-for="(educationGroup,index) in educationGroupList"
    :key="index"
    :value='educationGroup.id'
    :v-if="educationGroup.id == 2">
    {{ educationGroup.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Option 2: Use `selected` attribute for `option`.

Here `selected` is an property that accepts dynamic value. So it should be prefixed with a `:` and its value should be assigned with a condition on which the selection must be done. He in the below example `:selected="educationGroup.id == 1"`. So the option with `id` valie `1` will be selected.

```
<select class="form-select" name="" id="">
  <option
    v-for="(educationGroup,index) in educationGroupList"
    :key="index"
    :value='educationGroup.id'
    :v-if="educationGroup.id == 2"
    :selected="educationGroup.id == 1">
      {{ educationGroup.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Find the working example for both.

https://codepen.io/devkr/pen/poPRdWm